# CsvHelper: No members are mapped for type

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I use [CsvHelper 4.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/).

I have a **nested** class defined like this:

```
private class CsvLine {
    public string Solution;
    public string Project;
    public string DependsOnProject;
    public string Weight;
    public string DependsOnPackage;
    public string PackageVersion;
}
```

My .csv file, which I want to parse using `CsvHelper`, has these field names:

`Solution,Project,DependsOnProject,Weight,DependsOnPackage,PackageVersion`

Here is my code:

```
TextReader readFile = new StreamReader(dependenciesCsvFilePath);
var csvReader = new CsvReader(readFile);
IEnumerable<CsvLine> records = csvReader.GetRecords<CsvLine>();
```

According to the documentation [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/reading), the code above should work.

However, when I inspect `records`, I see the message `No members are mapped for type 'ParentClass+CsvLine'`.

I changed the accessibility of `CsvLine` from `private` to `public`, but that made no difference.

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** I have tried un-nesting the `CsvLine` class and making it public, but that did not help either.

**EDIT:** I made the changes as [Nkosi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058423/csvhelper-no-members-are-mapped-for-type/47058557#47058557); however, now it says that `records` is an empty collection: "Enumeration yielded no results". There are definitely data present inside my .csv file, so the collection shouldn't be empty.

Here are some sample data:

```
Solution,Project,DependsOnProject,Weight,DependsOnPackage,PackageVersion
FOD.sln,ABC.DEF,IMS.ABC,1,,
FOD.sln,ABC.DEF,IMS.DEF,1,,
FOD.sln,ABC.DEF,IMS.GHI,1,,
FOD.sln,ABC.DEF,IMS.JKL,1,,
```

**EDIT:** Solved! [Nkosi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47058557/3559686) and [Panagiotis'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47059214/3559686) answers complement each other's.

Comment: Same error when un-nested?

Comment: Fields verses properties.

Comment: Where Are the headers in the file? If no headers then you will have to create a class mapping to map by index

Comment: @Nkosi The headers are in the first line. I shall update my example.

Comment: Use `.GetRecords<CsvLine>().ToArray()` to load the data first, then check them. I've seen the debugger complain about an empty enumeration even though there were records. BTW which version of CsvHelper are you using? It changes versions almost every week

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos CsvHelper 4.0.3, as I mentioned in my post... :-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Calling ToArray() did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @MY_G check to see if it works with the fields as well *(which it should)*. If it does then I should remove my answer as it would no longer apply.

Comment: @MY_G you can add the `,results` format specifier in the watch window to force the debugger to evaluate the IEnumerable and return all results, eg `record,results`. Make sure you don't use this with large files though

Comment: @Nkosi Unfortunately it doesn't work with fields. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use Properties instead of fields in the object model as by default, it will map the matching public members

```
public class CsvLine {
    public string Solution { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string DependsOnProject { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public string DependsOnPackage { get; set; }
    public string PackageVersion { get; set; }
}
```

You should also read up on mapping your classes to the csv file.

[CsvHelper: Class Mapping](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I made the changes as you suggested; however, now it says that ``records`` is an empty collection: "Enumeration yielded no results". There are definitely data present inside my .csv file, so the collection shouldn't be empty.

Comment: I had same symptom as @my_g and resolved it by changing private setters to public setters on all properties.

Comment: Mind @robin-qiu answer

Answer (score 11):

Nkosi explained that CsvHelper maps to properties by default.

I've encountered the `Enumeration yielded no results` message in the debugger in the past. The message is misleading. There *are* records even though the debugger says there aren't. You iterate over the IEnumerable with `foreach` or call `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` on it to load all records, eg:

```
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<CsvLine>();
foreach(var record in records)
{
     ...
}
```

Or

```
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<CsvLine>().ToArray();
```

You can force the debugger to show all items in an IEnumerable in the Watch, Quick Watch or Immediate  window by adding the `results` [format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-csharp), eg:

```
records,results
```

Be careful because this will execute the IEnumerable and return all results.

You can find this, and other tricks in [7 Hidden Gems in Visual Studio 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/10/05/7-hidden-gems-in-visual-studio-2017/)

Comment: Thank you for this! I was trying to look at the results object in QuickWatch but it said "Enumeration yielded no results". After adding a foreach I can examine each record. Thank You!

 var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
 foreach(var record in records)
 {
     string recordObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(record);
 }

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier solution to the problem, it's only one line of code. You have to tell csvhelper to look at your fields.

```
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    csv.Configuration.MemberTypes = CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields;
.....
}
```

Comment: MemberTypes  is now readonly

Answer (score 4):

Other possible causes:

- Header string quote char.
- delimiter char.

Example code to config them:

```
var conf = new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration();
conf.Delimiter = ",";
conf.Quote = '\'';
var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader, conf);
var rows = csv.GetReads<MyClass>();
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue, even after adding a ClassMap. The delimiter was also involved in the case !

Answer (score 1):

As of CsvHelper 12.2.2, this is what I've had to do to get it to work

```
csv.Read() 
csv.ReadHeader()
csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
```

For some reason despite CsvReader's documentation, adding the Read() and ReadHeader() methods will get it to actually pull in the data from the csv file.