# CsvHelper Object reference not set to instance of object (GetRecords issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

I am following [this example](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started#reading-a-csv-file). As far as I can tell the `GetRecords` call is failing when I make a request to the `GetHist` endpoint, but I don't understand why.

**I checked that:**

1. My data follows the exact naming conventions of the c# class (I copied the names from the csv to create the variable names in c#)
2. The file input path is correct.
3. Im using the latest version of CsvHelper (12.1.0)

**Stack trace from the GetData call:**

> "   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecordsT+MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()"

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CsvHelper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class DataController : Controller
{

    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public DataController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<OHLCData> GetHist()
    {
        var v=OHLCData.GetData(_hostingEnvironment);
        return v;
    }

    public class OHLCData
    {
        string time;
        double oask, hask, lask, cask, obid, hbid, lbid, cbid;
        int volume;

        //@TODO: shouldnt pass it to this class from controller, should set in startup and read in this method
        public static IEnumerable<OHLCData> GetData(IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment)
        {
            string filepath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "EUR_USD.csv");
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filepath))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                return csv.GetRecords<OHLCData>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058423/csvhelper-no-members-are-mapped-for-type). I needed to declare properties instead of fields to get the object mapping to work. ie change `string time;` and others to `public string time {get;set;}`

Comment: Using fields should work fine. If you don't have a `ClassMap` that maps to the field, you can change a config setting to use fields instead of properties, or both for that matter. `csv.Configuration.MemberTypes = CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields;`