# No members mapped for type - CSV Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, csvhelper

I am new to using CSVHelper and AutoMapper and am getting the following error when trying to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (BolCsv != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(BolCsv.OpenReadStream()))
                    using (var csvr = new CsvReader(reader, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                    {
                        csvr.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";
                        csvr.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
                        csvr.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;

                        var bolDtos = csvr.GetRecords<BOLDto>().ToList();
                        var bols = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BOL>>(bolDtos);

                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        return RedirectToPage("./Index");

                    }
                }
```

```
var bolDtos = csvr.GetRecords<BOLDto>();
```

Error: No members are mapped for type 'BOLDto'.

BOLDto:

```
{
    public class BOLDto
    {
        [Name("BOLNumber")]
        public int BOLNumber { get; set; }
        [Name("ProductID")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [Name("ProductDescription")]
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        
etc...

   }
}
```

BOL.cs:

```
{
    public class BOL
    {
        public int BOLNumber { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        
etc...

    }
}
```

As I mentioned Im new to ASP.Net Core AutoMapper, and CSVHelper... how do I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Uh... all the properties in your BOL class are private (default accessibility). Is this intentional?

Comment: Try calling `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` like suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47059214/10839134

Comment: Oops sorry - edit included public on properties. I also tried .ToList() and get the same error

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `BOLDto` class has `properties`, but that error message is the same as I would get if the class had `fields` instead of `properties`.  So you might want to try `CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields`.  Also that must be an older version of `CsvHelper` you are using, because that is not how you would need to set up the configuration in the current version. But it should still work for you to add `csvr.Configuration.MemberTypes = CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<BOLDto, BOL>());
    var _mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = "\t",
        HeaderValidated = null,
        MissingFieldFound = null,
        MemberTypes = CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields
    };

    using (var reader = new StringReader("BOLNumber\tProductID\tProductDescription\t\n1\t2\tMy Product"))
    using (var csvr = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
    {
        var bolDtos = csvr.GetRecords<BOLDto>().ToList();
        var bols = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BOL>>(bolDtos);
    }
}

public class BOLDto
{
    [Name("BOLNumber")]
    public int BOLNumber;
    [Name("ProductID")]
    public int ProductID;
    [Name("ProductDescription")]
    public string ProductDescription;
}

public class BOL
{
    public int BOLNumber { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see getters and setters in OP's code.

Comment: @mxmissile I saw that as well.  I just know the error message matches what I would get if they were fields instead of properties. OP might have simplified the code for the example and not even realized that the fields got changed to properties. So, yes, if the OP's code is exactly as posted, then my solution likely won't help and there is a different issue.